# html css gallery grid with image popup viewer

Tags: html, css, image-gallery, css-grid

I tried to make an image gallery with differently sized images, popup image viewer and a normal grid.In addition I should be able to download the image just by clicking on it. Unfortunately I totally messed up with the css code. 
What is the error that I still do not get the desired grid in my gallery?

my code:

```css
#thumbwrap {
  margin: 75px auto;
  width: 252px;
  height: 252px;
}

.thumb {
  float: left;
  /* must be floated for same cross browser position of larger image */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 200px;
  align-items: center;
}

.thumb img {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  max-width: 100%;
}

.thumb:hover {
  border: 0;
  /* IE6 needs this to show large image */
  z-index: 1;
}

.thumb span {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.thumb:hover span {
  visibility: visible;
  top: 37px;
  left: 37px;
}
```

```html
<div id="thumbwrap">
  <a class="thumb" download="" href="/path/to/image.jpg"><img alt="" height="auto" src="/path/to/image.jpg" width="200" /><span><img alt="" src="/path/to/image.jpg" /></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: If you run this on chrome (if you have chrome) and inspect element and find this code, it will tell you if you have any coding bugs. If it’s not the desired output but all code works, I can’t help.